# Contentful rich text removing css class on adding new option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, contentful

I am using contentful inside my Next.js project

I am having an issue with contentful rich text whereby when I add a new option it removes the css class from my first option and apply's the second option only. Cannot understand why this is. The options code is as follows:

```
const options = {

renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => {
        return (
            <p className="text-primary">{children}</p>
        )
    }
},
renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.LIST_ITEM]: (node, children) => {
        return (
            <li className="text-sundown">{children}</li>
        )
    }
}
```

};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you can't have muliple `renderNode` property inside `options`. Put paragraph and list-item css inside one `renderNode`.

```
const options = {

renderNode: {
    [BLOCKS.PARAGRAPH]: (node, children) => {
        return (
            <p className="text-primary">{children}</p>
        )
    },
    [BLOCKS.LIST_ITEM]: (node, children) => {
        return (
            <li className="text-sundown">{children}</li>
        )
    }
};
```

Comment: Ahhh, silly mistake. Thank you so much. Now fixed :)